# What causes grape leaves to brown and how do I correct it?

Tags: diagnosis, leaves, grape-vine

I have planted two types of grapes along with a passion fruit vine that I want to cover an arbour for shade in the summer and fruit of course. I planted them in December and they grew fairly well until we got a couple hot and humid weeks followed by a lot of rain. We are just into autumn now (Gold Coast Australia) and I have just worked the garden soil by breaking the existing soil slightly with a garden fork and adding a mix of 1 part chicken manure, 1 part cow manure, 1 part soil on top and finally then covered with 5cm  of mulch. One end is done this way and intend to finish the other side soon (for autumn/winter crops) Since I have redone the soil a week ago for the Black Muscat Grape and Passion Fruit vines, the Black Muscat has started to grow again and has fresh green leaves. I didn't expect it to do that as we are in Autumn heading into winter and the passion fruit has now started blooming (no problem with leaves) and we have 10 or so fruits on it now. The White Muscat however has had very little change (some small amount of new growth) but I have not redone the soil around it, just gave it a light covering of the new soil. I want to understand why the leaves browned so I can make sure I give them the best health for spring and summer to grow well. For watering we used the hose initially until I added the misting system to the arbour (black pipes running underneath the main cross members). It waters the grass and the garden beds with a continuous light mist. We haven't used the misters for two months or so now as the ground is still very wet and the occasional rains keep it all moist. I think maybe the browning leaves was caused by the nearly two weeks of heavy rain we had in January which followed the high heat and humidity. The ground with the grass is still very damp without any watering which has allowed the burnt areas to regrow but soil in the lower garden bed is now crumbly/moist not damp/wet with plenty of worms before I added the new soil and watered in.

[image]
The arbour has three sections. Closest section has the Black Muscat, centre section the passion fruit, and the furthest section the White Muscat

[image]
Black Muscat: 4 months of growth

[image]
Black Muscat: New Growth

[image]
Black Muscat: Damaged leaves

[image]
Passion Fruit: No issues, the dead vines are from a rock melon plant eaten by caterpillars :(

[image]
White Muscat: 4 months growth, this end struggled early on until we realised we didn't water it properly and the soil was quite dry underneath.

[image]
White Muscat: Damaged leaves

[image]
White Muscat: Very few leaves remain undamaged/may even be new growth

[image]
White Muscat: New growth

Comment: Doesn't look like any of the  terrible diseases. I saw a grapevine's leaves changing for autumn four days ago, but that was in victoria. try to keep the leaves dry, especially in summer.

Comment: those raised planting beds they're growing in - are they open at the bottom onto  soil, or sealed off, meaning the planting depth is quite shallow?

Comment: The lower one is open to the ground level, and the ground level is roughly 6 to 8 inches deep before it hits solid rock/limestone. The taller one has been back filled with debis but we are not really planting anything in them except succulents which love it in there.